# What is the pronoun "their" being used to refer to?

Tags: meaning, pronouns, research

> The biofilms are able to break down the pesticides that contaminate aquatic environments and modify their structure, diversity and functioning.

Here's the whole text:

> A team from Cemagref in Lyon (FR) has identified a pertinent indicator of the level of pollution in rivers: the biofilm.A complex combination of bacteria, algae and fungi, the biofilm forms a viscous layer on immersed supports, such as the stones on a river bed. **The biofilms are able to break down the pesticides that contaminate aquatic environments and modify their structure, diversity and functioning.** Toxic substances, for example, can change the photosynthetic, respiratory or enzymatic activity of aquatic ecosystems, either definitively or temporarily. It is in this way that biofilms can serve as an early warning signal of pollution.

One more question: 
How do biofilms indicate the river pollution? (Could you explain meaning of the text please.)

Comment: Where did you find the text?

Comment: "their" is a possessive adjective. The relevant possessive pronoun is "theirs".

Comment: i found it from research eu magazine

Comment: The sentence needs replacing, though 'modifying their diversity' can hardly make sense if applied to 'pesticides'. Hence << The biofilms are able to break down the pesticides that: _contaminate aquatic environments and modify their structure, diversity and functioning_. >>

Comment: The natural interpretation is that the genitive (possessive) pronoun "their" refers to "the pesticides that contaminate aquatic environments", but without any technical knowledge of the subject we can't be 100% certain.

Comment: @BillJ given the context (i.e. the next sentence), I'd say it's referring to the environment in this instance.

Comment: @marcellothearcane yes you are right

Comment: The question calls for an interpretation of one particular text; answering it will not provide any general insight into English language and usage.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

I believe I can answer your question.

"Their" in this context is referring to the pesticide. That is the pesticides structure is what is being modified by the biofilm.

Whilst I am no ecological or chemistry wizard, it sounds like "Biofilms" are a compound which are used to break down the pesticides in the environment, thus saving the environment from the damaging effects of the pesticides.

The specific question of how it indicates river pollution appears to be related to the existence of the Biofilms as a relative indicator of the pollution.

More pollution, more biofilms, I presume that biofilms are easier to measure than the pollution itself and thus this is why this method is used.

Comment: I'm not sure. On its own, the sentence does seem to support that interpretation, but the following sentence seems to imply that it's the pesticides which modify the structure etc. of aquatic environments.

Comment: @KateBunting I agree its not at all obvious, but when the following sentences goes on to explain the effects of the pesticide on the environment I think its a reasonable assumption to make. More importantly the sentence we are focusing on, identifies the pesticides as the target of the descriptions. The actor is the biolfilm.

Comment: The use of *their* is ambiguous, so there can be no definitive answer without asking the author. However, I strongly think that *their* is referring to **aquatic environments**, not to pesticides. *Biofilms break down pesticides. Pesticides contaminate aquatic environments and then modify the structure, diversity and functioning of **those aquatic environments**.* There is nothing about the sentences that follow that precludes this interpretation; in fact, the sentences that follow suggest it.